# RSpec + FactoryGirl and controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to add FactoryGirl support the default scaffolded specs in my controllers and I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Here's an example test:

```
describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
   it "creates a new Course" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:course => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        }.to change(Course, :count).by(1)
      end
do
```

Which I replace by:

```
describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Course" do
        expect {
          post :create, course: FactoryGirl.build(:course)
        }.to change(Course, :count).by(1)
      end
do
```

spec/factories/courses.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    association :provider
    name "Course name"
    description "course description"
  end
end
```

app/models/course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :provider_id, :presence => true
  has_many :terms
  belongs_to :provider
end
```

app/controllers/courses_controller.rb

```
  # POST /courses
  # POST /courses.json

  def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It usually fails with: "ActionController::ParameterMissing: param not found: course" does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!
Francis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
    describe "POST create" do
        describe "with valid params" do
          it "creates a new Course" do
            expect {
              post :create, course: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:course, provider_id: 1)
            }.to change(Course, :count).by(1)
          end
        end
     end
```

Factory Girl uses `attributes_for` option to generate a hash of values as opposed to a Ruby object.

Comment: I tried this previously but spec fails with: "count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0"

Comment: Can you post your `:course` factory, your `create` action in `courses_controller` and `Course` model? Your test is now failing as opposed to having an error.

Comment: Updated my original post with factory data as requested.

Comment: Could it be failing because the course you are trying to create has no `provider_id`? Try `post :create, course: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:course, provider_id: 1)` to see if the test passes.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it! Was under the impression that the association in the factory would create the required provider...

Comment: Please note that this is just a temporary fix to debug the error. I don't know what your `:provider` factory looks like. Maybe you need to create a `provider` instance before each test.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41669/discussion-between-francis-ouellet-and-abm)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I thought with the association declaration, when we create use `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:course)`, it would create a `provider` entry and then associate with `course`.